# proof validation of dimension inequalities

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

**The Porblem Is:**

$A+B=\left \{ a+b : a\in A, b\in B \right \}$ and $C$ is a vectorspace and $A \subset C, B \subset C$.

Let $a_1,..,a_n$ be elements of $A$ and let $b_1,..,b_k$ be elements of $B$ be two families of vectors in $C$. Let $A=\operatorname{Span}(a_1,..,a_n)$ and $b=\operatorname{Span}(b_1,..,b_k)$

Now, Show that $\mathbf{dim}(A+B)\leq n+k$ and show that $\mathbf{dim}(A+B)\leq \mathbf{dim}(C)$

**The proof i found:**

[image]

**The Questions**

Now, I have 2 things that I would like explained/validated.

- For the first proof; Why is the index for $\beta$ and $b$ now $i$ and the sum index is $i$ and not $t$?
- For the second proof I just do not understand the "proof" from "Basis of $C$ is... [...]". It does not seem clear to me what the author is trying to say. Does someone have an idea or can further clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The first point is just a notational choice. The author wanted to make it clear that the two sets of indices for the $\alpha$'s and $\beta's$ were distinct (and thus ranged over a potentially different number of terms: $n$ and $k$ respectively in this case)

For the second part, the author is just using one of the definitions of a basis, i.e., "a linearly independent set with the largest possible number of elements". The cardinality of such a set is defined to be the dimension of $C$, so the dimension can be thought of as the maximum number of linearly independent vectors you can find. Since $(A+B)\subset C$ a basis $\{e_1,\dotsc, e_s\}$ of $A+B$ is a linearly independent set sitting inside $C$ with $s$ elements. Thus $s\leq \dim C$.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot! For the second part; the formulation of the author is throwing me off. It is almost as words are missing. Having a real hard time following it because of that.

Comment: When you say "maximum number of linearly independent vectors you can find" what do you mean by you can find? Is that jus the maximum number of linearly independent vectors that are in $C$?

Comment: Yeah, "the most vectors you can collect in a linearly independent list" is what I mean. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example, any list of four vectors has a linear dependence relation, so $\dim \mathbb{R}^3<4$.

Comment: could you possible write the proof for the second inequality? I would love to see it.

Comment: Which inequality specifically are you referring to?

Comment: the one with the most confusion; $\mathbf{dim}(A+B)\leq \mathbf{dim}(C)$ this one

Comment: I just can not understand it the way it is currently written out with the lack of words and without hurting anyone - the broken english.